# Question about product of invertible matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be an $n\,\rm{x}\,n$ matrix. Prove that there exists a matrix $B$ of the same size and $B$ is invertible such that $BA$ is upper-triangular.

Comment: Think about the diagonalization of A

Comment: Using a QR factorization, we can decompose the matrix $A$ into a product $A = QR$ of an orthogonal matrix $Q$ and an upper triangular matrix $R$.

Comment: The simpler theory for $QR$ (because generally seen in lessons) is to use Gram-Schmidt orthonormalization on the columns vectors of $A$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We prove this by induction on $n$. For $n = 1$, the statement is obvious.

Let $X$ be the first column of $A$. If $X \ne 0$, there is some invertible $B_1$ such that $B_1 X = (1, 0, \dots, 0)^t$. If $X = 0$, we let $B_1$ be an arbitrary $n \times n$ invertible matrix.

Now write
$$
B_1 A =
\begin{pmatrix}
 * & * \\
0 & A_1
\end{pmatrix},
$$
in block form, where $A_1$ is an $(n-1) \times (n - 1)$ matrix.

By the induction hypothesis, there is some invertible $B_2$ such that $B_2 A_1$ is upper triangular.

Now let
$$
B = 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & B_2
\end{pmatrix}
B_1.
$$
Then $B$ satisfies the required conditions.

Answer (score 2):

Can you make $A$ upper triangular by performing elementary row operations?

Can you write an elementary row operation as left-multiplication by a simple matrix?

Can you write a sequence of elementary row operations as left-multiplication by a single matrix (which matrix is the product of a bunch of single operation matrices)?

Comment: Is there a way to prove this by using induction combine with elementary matrices?

Comment: @Harry : You tell me.